How to set sigterm_timeout in ROS2 launch file?
The default escalate to sigterm time is currently 5 seconds. How can I change it?
[MAP] [ERROR] [map_acc_Map-1]: process[map_acc_Map-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[MAP] [INFO] [map_acc_Map-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[map_acc_Map-1]
[MAP] [ERROR] [map_acc_Map-1]: process has died [pid 4162, exit code -15, cmd '/home/orca/pb_nx/install/map_acc/lib/map_acc/map_acc_Map --ros-args -r __node:=map_acc_Map --params-file /tmp/launch_params_dgd5illc --params-file /tmp/launch_params_xvb3pmnz --params-file /tmp/launch_params_r0xnecz8 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_wf_hwdqd'].


Try this:
   ros2 launch test.launch.py sigterm_timeout:=30

See this previous answer.
